# "error deserializing the object of type Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IdentifiableObjectData" while editing image in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1

I have created a page and tried to edit the image and text from XPM, I am able to do edit content/textbox from XPM but in case of image its showing an error. Below is the error which I got.
Also when I tried to edit the same component from CMS then its working fine for all fields.

> (80040356) Unable to save item
>     The formatter threw an exception
>   while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while
>   trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2013:deltaData.
>   The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the
>   object of type Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IdentifiableObjectData.
>   There are multiple root elements. Line 37, position 21.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

I am using SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 version and using the same version of XPM.

Comment: Are you able to save the same image with same changes through CME?

Comment: Yes, through CMS I am able to save same or different image while using XPM  and tried to do edit with same image showing the issue.

Comment: The webapp, is that static or dynamic (dd4t or some kind)

Comment: This is pure DWT based static page....and i used below XPM tags for image
<!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:image[1]"} -->
   <img src="@@Component.Fields.image@@" tridion:type="Multimedia" alt="image" />